# Is $\sum_n\exp(ian+ibn^2+icn^3)$ known in terms of anything else?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, fourier-series, distribution-theory, theta-functions

For arbitrary $a,b,c$, does the series
$$F(a,b,c)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(ian+ibn^2+icn^3\right),$$
i.e. an evenly-weighed series of exponentials of cubic polynomials, converge to anything known? I'm aware that it is very ugly and I am willing to go to some lengths to meet the thing halfway.

I know, for example, that if $c=0$ the series reduces in essence to a [Jacobi theta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2), $\theta_3$, which requires $\operatorname{Im}(b)>0$ to make sense. In my application $b$ is real, which doesn't by itself doom the series but does make it very difficult for it to converge. On the other hand, I'm happy to take a distribution-valued function, which is essentially equivalent to saying I'm happy to assume $\operatorname{Im}(b)>0$ if needed.

Away from the theta-function case, though, as soon as $c$ steps away from zero (which I do *need* to do), every resource I've tried goes belly-up.

Is there some known function which encapsulates this behaviour? Failing that, I'd also be interested in applications where this or similar objects came up and people were forced to just deal with it directly.

Comment: I think people have tried and essentially failed to understand things like $e^{ix^3}$ and its Fourier transform, apart from generalities. Automorphic forms people and certain physicists would certainly be interested in any low-hanging fruit in this direction... and have looked for it... and, so far as I know, found nothing. (That means "nothing explicit/elementary".)

Comment: @Paul I might need to get on the physicist-looking-for-low-hanging-fruit queue, then.

Comment: A physicist would maybe try asymptotic expansions...

Comment: @tired I'm mainly interested in exact results. However, any handles on this series would be useful.